# How to pass an argument to a shell/bash script using vboxmanage cli from windows cmd line?

Tags: bash, powershell, shell, virtualbox, powershell-2.0

I have a VM running in Oracle Virtual box. Within this VM, I have some bash/shell scripts and also defined few global variables like `export abc=123`

Script in vm,

```
#!/bin/bash 
echo testing
echo $abc
```

Within vm if I run this script using `bash test.sh` i get output as

```
testing
123
```

If I run below command from windows command prompt, I get `testing` as output but I don't get `123`. I just get a blank space in output. How can my vboxmanage command get the value of,`abc` variable defined in my vm.

```
testing
```

Command in windows cli,

```
VBoxManage guestcontrol vm-name run /bin/sh --exe  "test.sh" --username user --password pass --verbose --wait-stdout --wait-stderr
```

Comment: Maybe the `abc` variable is only set up and exported for login shells and maybe the `VBoxManage` thing doesn't run a login shell.

Comment: Maybe Windows is being stupid and cutting off the second line, try `echo "testing: $abc"`

Comment: Run `set` in windows cmd prompt and check if you see your `abc` variable there

Comment: The command establishes a new login to your linux, under username "user".  Is the `abc` variable set automatically at login for the "user" ?  Like in a bashrc file maybe?

Comment: I guess @Nic3500 is correct. I guess we need to set the variable systemwide either through bashrc or environment file. Let me try this and come back

Comment: @MarkSetchell it has nothing to do with Windows. Obviously an environment variable inside a machine (VM in this case) can't be seen in another computer

Comment: @phuclv The script runs inside the virtual machine where it can see all the files, processes and environment inside that machine. The result is then displayed on the Windows machine, where it can be seen as the output of the `VBoxManage` command. So, I disagree. I think the Linux environment variable CAN be made visible to Windows.

Comment: @MarkSetchell it can be made visible, but not by a simple `export abc=123`

Comment: @phuclv I wasn't suggesting that `export abc=123` on the Linux VM would make `abc` visible on the Windows host. Maybe you are referring to Vivere's comment?